# WX Blocks Not Installed in GNURadio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

I was trying to install GNURadio on my Ubuntu 16.04 using the follwoing command:

`wget http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio && chmod a+x build-gnuradio && ./build-gnuradio`

which is found on the following GNURadio webpage link:

(http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource)

First, when the script was checking for packages, I noticed the following two warning messages:

"Failed to find package 'python-wxgtk2.8' in known package repositories. Some things may not build as a result"

"Failed to find package 'libzmq1-dev' in known package repositories. Some things may not build as a result"

which at the end did not install the WX GUI or the associated WX GNURadio blocks. I tried to manually install "python-wxgtk2.8" using the following command:

`sudo get-apt install python-wxgtk2.8`

but I got the the following message:

"Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source"

I am not sure if this is an Ubuntu 16.04 or GNURadio issue. Could you please provide a step-by-step instructions on how to solve this issue and have the WX blocks installed in my GNURadio?

Comment: you could try `python-wxgtk3.0` instead. That's what pybombs does.

Comment: I installed the `python-wxgtk3.0`. I tried to run the GNURadio installation script from the link above but got the same warning about wxgtk2.8. Is there a way to install the WX module to GNURadio in a way that avoid this issue?

Comment: Well, aside from the warning, was gr-wxgui built? By the way: GNU Radio had QT GUI, which is more modern an can be used as substitute of wxgui, but then not all applications will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to install python-wxgtk3.0 using sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0 it may report it as already the newest version.

You can modify the script to reflect the change from python-wxgtk2.8 to python-wxgtk3.0 in the section for version 16.*

And change libzmq1.dev to libzmq.dev in the section for version 16.*

This was also recommended here
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271836